# Replacing an Actionscript with jQuery

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3

Take a look at this site. The site is built in Actionscript and needs to be converted to jQuery/Javascript can this be done?

http://www.nonsek.com/machine.php

Let know your opinions

Comment: if you're concerned about having your website displayable on apple's mobile devices, your current best bet, in my opinion, is to employ SWFObject to display static content in HTML (or some lite CSS3 animation) if Flash is not available.  while Apple and other promote the advancement of HTML5, it's current overall graphical performance on mobile devices is very poor.

Comment: Thanks...I was thinking that myself. Was also thinking of using HTML 5 Canvas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big animations will be slow on most browsers. IE9 is doing very good since they implemented GPU rendering for that purpose. Browsers that are based on WebKit will take big animations badly, at least for now.

It is totally fine to replace actionscript with javascript on little animations, but on big ones like yours I don't think it will be a good idea. There is a reason why pretty sites with huge amount of animation are made with actionscript instead of javascript.

Comment: Well I am not saying all of the animation because it is redundant but the functionality can be done?

Comment: In theory all the animation and functionality on the website you presented is possible to make using JavaScript. The quality of the final product, however, will depend on what will be written in JS and what will stay on AS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. (unless you count rewriting the whole thing as conversion)

Comment: how are you going to replicate the animation? I'm curious. I don't know any js library out there that can do these animations.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do such thing (Actionscript to Javascript conversion) could be to use [Haxe](http://haxe.org/doc/intro). 
You could use an Actionscript to Haxe converter ([there](http://code.google.com/p/actionscripttohaxe/) [are](http://code.google.com/p/qundash/) [many](https://github.com/geekrelief/as3tohaxe)), and then target JS from Haxe.

The conversion process would still require supervision and *manual* labor, it would just help you get started. Then you would have to modify that code so that it's suitable to target the JS platform.

That would be a lazy way, that in my opinion could end up giving you more work. Also, it would require that you to learn Haxe in some depth (which is a Good thing, but requires some time which would be a nuance if you are in a tight schedule )

But still, I think the arguments presented by Qmal and  TheDarkIn1978 are valid ones that you should consider.